# How to pass mutation variables to render function?

Tags: javascript, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have the following child component:

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.onClick(this.state.email, this.state.password);            
    }

    handleEmailChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({email: e.target.value});
    }

    handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
       this.setState({password: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
            <Input id="email" name="email" autoComplete="email" autoFocus 
                        value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange}/>

            <Input name="password" type="password" id="password" autoComplete="current-password" 
                        value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}/>
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

Now from the parent I have the following component:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        email: "",
        password: ""
    }
}

handleClick(e, p, request) {
    request();
}

render() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    console.log('render', email, password); // here I see the right state after click
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <Mutation mutation={LOGIN} variables={{ email: email, password: password }} onError={() => {}}>
            {(request, result) => {
                const { data, loading, error, called } = result;
                if(!called) {
                    return <SignIn onClick={(e, p) => this.handleClick(e, p, request)} />;
                }
                if(error) {
                    return <div>Error</div>;
                }
                if(loading) {
                    return <div>Loading...</div>;
                }
                ...
                return <div>Mutation processed</div>;
            }}
            </Mutation>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
    }
}
```

What I wanted to achieve is separate handler after button click and initiate mutation send after some logic. However, this way variables(email, password) are always sent empty to the network. If I put `request` directly into handle, then it works.

How can I have a handler outside of `render` function to initiate mutation request with correct variable values? I would also very much like to know why this construction doesn't work and variables are empty.

Comment: Can you try `let { email, password } ` instead of `const { email, password } `

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan: it's same.

Comment: whats the `e` and `p` in  `<SignIn onClick={(e, p) => this.handleClick(e, p, request)} />;` ?

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan it's email and password coming from SignIn component via `handleClick` handler, combined with `request` object for initiating request.

Comment: can you post the `request()` method

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan, no, because it's not my method, but provided by `react-apollo`. I just call it.

Comment: I've solved it by passing variables inside request like this: `request({variables: {email: e, password: p}})`. So it might be some safety mechanism preventing me to setState inside render to prevent infinite loop. Still interesting to know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here lies with the line:

`this.onClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`

With incorrect binding you're not going to trigger the method you want. This *should* be:

`this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`

The following achieves what you want. I've slimmed it down because I don't know anything about your Apollo implementation, but hopefully you'll get the gist:

```
// SignIn.jsx

import React, { Component } from "react";

class SignIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onClick(this.state.email, this.state.password);
  };

  handleEmailChange = e => {
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
  };

  handlePasswordChange = e => {
    this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id="email"
          name="email"
          autoComplete="email"
          autoFocus
          value={this.state.email}
          onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
        />

        <input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          id="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
          value={this.state.password}
          onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
        />

        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignIn;

// App.jsx

import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import SignIn from "./SignIn";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  handleClick(e, p, request) {
    console.log("Requesting: ", request);
  }

  render() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const request = "Your Apollo Request";
    console.log("render", email, password); // here I see the right state after click
    return (
      <div>
        <SignIn onClick={(e, p) => this.handleClick(e, p, request)} />;
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This didn't work. The bound function is not even necessary as I am using arrow function as handler. The method is being triggered, but with _empty_ variables. The problem is probably related to Apollo mutation.

Comment: @Pablo I think I know what the issue is- it can be difficult to build “dynamic” queries/mutations in Apollo. I will revert to you when I have had a chance to look into it in more detail.

Comment: see my comment in original post